# New environment using tasks

Tags: macros, environments, tasks

I'm trying to create a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{tasksx}{
    \begin{tasks}[counter-format = (tsk[a]), after-item-skip = -.5ex, before-skip = -2.5em, after-skip = 1em]
        \task
    \end{tasks}
}
```

But when I try to compile:

```
Text 
\begin{tasksx}(3)
\task 1
\task 2
\task 3
\task 4
\task 5
\end{tasksx}
```

I get the error: `!Undefined control sequence. \task 1`

Answer (score 1):

In order to define a new environment that behaves like the `tasks` environment, the `tasks` package offers the `\NewTasks` command. The general usage of this command is `\NewTasks[〈options〉]{〈name〉}[〈separator〉](〈cols〉)`  as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\NewTasks[counter-format = (tsk[a]), after-item-skip = -.5ex, before-skip = -2.5em, after-skip = 1em]{mytask}[\task](1)
\begin{document}
\begin{mytask}
\task bla
\end{mytask}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the `before-skip` doesn't work. It keeps the same space, no matter what I change.

Comment: @mvfs314; You are right. I have been overlooking this. Does `before-skip` work if you use it as an option to `\begin{tasks}` in your document?

Comment: yes, it does work. I'm almost using this in case `\NewTasks`doesn't work.

Comment: actually, no, `before-skip` just works when I use it in the preamble with `settasks`

Comment: @mvfs314: That's exactly what I observed. If you want to use the same settings for all `tasks` environments in your doument, it might be best, to just use `\settasks` instead of defining an own environment using `\NewTasks`.

Comment: But, please, see my problem on this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425014/newtasks-environment-before-skip